# Javascript listener add text from first text_field to second text_field after converting to slug

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, listener

I am trying to add a javascript listener that:
1. Listens for text changes in a text field (#articleField)
2. Converts that text into a slug
3. Places that new slug into another text field (#slugField)

I am using Rails 4
I am pulling the slug logic from [this question:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14513546/jquery-trying-to-create-slug-target-anchors)

view

```
  <%= f.input :article, label: 'Article', required: true, focus: true, id: 'articleField' %>
  <%= f.input :slug, label: 'Slug', required: true, focus: true, id: 'slugField' %>
  <%= f.button :submit, value: 'SAVE CHANGES' %>'



 <script>
$('#articleField').blur(  
   function(){    
      var article = $(this).text();
      var slug = article.trim().toLowerCase().replace(" ", "_");
      $(this).prop('id', slug);
      $(slug).append(#slugField); <---this is where I'm going off the road
    } 
  )
// </script>
```

I am new to JS and am having trouble with how to append the #slugField text box with the slug created in the function.

Comment: Better use change and/or keyup events because blur event will be fired only on focus lost, that's odd ui behaviour as for web.
$('#articleField').on('change keyup', function(){ ... });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, is your javascript code inside a `document` `ready` instruction?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    // Your code should be here
  });
</script>
```

Second, you can use `jQuery` `val` method to set the text inside the `text_field`.

```
$('#articleField').blur(function() {
  var article = $(this).val();
  var slug = article.trim().toLowerCase().replace(" ", "_");
  $("#slugField").val(slug);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For creating slug I use a jquery plugin that works really well speakingurl, from http://pid.github.io/speakingurl/

Now My code, I get the slug on the change and keyup methods, get the slug based on the input value and assign it to other field.

```
$(document).on('keyup change','#username', function(){
    var slug = getSlug($(this).val());
    $('#user-slug').val(slug);
    //looking for optimization
    delete slug;
});
```

Hope that you understand.